# Cron delayed, then run paraller my cronned tasks

Tags: linux, debian, cron

on my debian servers i have cronned MyTask via my own perl script (serviceManager.pl) to every minute.

```
# crontab -e

* * * * * $SCRIPTS_PATH/serviceManager.pl MyTask
```

Problem is sometimes is task not launched in same time as is logged in cron.

Task is delayed and then is run paraller with same task.
This cause my script report error, because another task with same name is running.
I am using my own locking (for reason of logging) but lock is corruped, because second task is executed before task is locked.

```
# This is my own interpretation of issue based on data from syslog and serviceManager (my script) log :

07:13:01 - CRON in syslog : launching MyTask  - correct launched task.
07:13:02 - serviceManager log : starting MyTask
07:13:03 - serviceManager log : finishing MyTask
07:14:01 - CRON in syslog : launching MyTask
---- nothing between in both logs ----
07:15:01 - CRON in syslog : launching MyTask
07:15:27 serviceManager log : 4552] STARTING: [MyTask]
07:15:27 serviceManager log : 4552] ERROR     [MyTask] : 'serviceManager.pl MyTask' is running with PID 4391
07:15:27 serviceManager log : 4391] STARTING: [MyTask]
07:15:27 serviceManager log : 4391] IS LOCKED:[MyTask]
```

I see there is another cron log entries in syslog,
something like :

```
Sep 24 07:13:22 myserver crontab[4294]: (myuser) LIST (myuser)
```

Between 07:14:01 and 07:15:01 there is no one 'crontab' entry.
Can this be cause of that error ?

Answers like 'call system command lockfile before your perl script' is not relevant.
I want to know what is wrong with cron.

This behaviour is not only in one of my servers.
Servers aren't cloned, but have same versions of debian (and cron package)

If you have experience with this kind of cron issue, i appreciate any advice.

```
# syslog :

Sep 24 07:13:01 myserver CRON[4155]: (myuser) CMD ($SCRIPTS_PATH/serviceManager.pl MyTask)
Sep 24 07:13:12 myserver crontab[4266]: (myuser) LIST (myuser)
Sep 24 07:13:13 myserver crontab[4269]: (myuser) LIST (myuser)
Sep 24 07:13:22 myserver crontab[4293]: (myuser) LIST (myuser)
Sep 24 07:13:22 myserver crontab[4294]: (myuser) LIST (myuser)

Sep 24 07:14:01 myserver CRON[4391]: (myuser) CMD ($SCRIPTS_PATH/serviceManager.pl MyTask)
Sep 24 07:15:01 myserver CRON[4552]: (myuser) CMD ($SCRIPTS_PATH/serviceManager.pl MyTask)
Sep 24 07:15:18 myserver crontab[4836]: (myuser) LIST (myuser)


# serviceManager log :

[2016/09/24 07:13:02 | 4155] STARTING: [MyTask]
[2016/09/24 07:13:03 | 4155] FINISHING:[MyTask]
[2016/09/24 07:15:27 | 4552] STARTING: [MyTask]
[2016/09/24 07:15:27 | 4552] ERROR     [MyTask] : 'serviceManager.pl MyTask' is running with PID 4391
[2016/09/24 07:15:27 | 4391] STARTING: [MyTask]
[2016/09/24 07:15:27 | 4391] IS LOCKED:[MyTask]
```

System info :

> ```
> cron version : 3.0pl1-127+deb8u1 / amd64
>
>   Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 8.5 (jessie)
>             Kernel: Linux 3.2.0-4-amd64
>       Architecture: x86-64
> ```

Comment: System load could cause the `cron` job to be delayed after it starts.  There is no guarantee that it will finish within a minute every time, so your code needs to cope with this.  Not really a programming question, anyway.